# How to solve it in simple ways, Find $f'(0)$

Tags: derivatives

$f(x) = \dfrac{\left(x-3\right)\left(x-2\right)\left(x-1\right)x}{\left(x+1\right)\left(x+2\right)\left(x+3\right)}$

Find $f'(0)$

By apply the Quotient Rule $\frac{f'g - g'f}{g^2} $, I can find the answer but it's too long.

Is there any other methods to simplify the steps?

Answer (score 1):

Take $\log$:

\begin{align*}
&\log f(x)\\
&=\log(x-3)+\log(x-2)+\log(x-1)+\log x-\log(x+1)-\log(x+2)-\log(x+3)\\
&\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{x-3}+\dfrac{1}{x-2}+\dfrac{1}{x-1}+\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x+1}-\dfrac{1}{x+2}-\dfrac{1}{x+3}\\
&f'(x)\\
&=f(x)\left(\dfrac{1}{x-3}+\dfrac{1}{x-2}+\dfrac{1}{x-1}+\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x+1}-\dfrac{1}{x+2}-\dfrac{1}{x+3}\right)
\end{align*}
and then plugging in $x=0$. But first cancel the same factor $x$ in $f(x)\cdot\dfrac{1}{x}$ and then plugging in $x=0$. For the other factors, they are zero.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html) before differentiation

$$f(x)=\dfrac{x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}=x+\dfrac A{x+1}+\dfrac B{x+2}+\dfrac C{x+3}$$

$$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)f(x)=?$$

Set $x=-1,-2,-3$ to find $A,B,C$

$$f'(0)=1-\dfrac A{1^2}-\dfrac B{2^2}-\dfrac C{3^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Put $y = f(x)$. Taking natural logarithm on both sides of the equation,

$$\ln(y) = \ln(x-3) + \ln(x-2) + \ln(x-1) + \ln(x) - \ln(x+1) - \ln(x+2) - \ln(x+3)$$

$$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x-3} + \frac{1}{x-2} + \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{1}{x+3}$$

Now, multiplying both sides by $y = f(x)$,

$$f'(x) = f(x)(\frac{1}{x-3} + \frac{1}{x-2} + \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{1}{x+3})$$

Then put $x = 0$.